# Access class inside function that was called inside class definition expression

Tags: python

Is it possible to access class from inside function that was called inside its definition expression?

```
def called_inside_definition():
    # I want to access 'Foo' here

class Foo:
    called_inside_definition()
```

*The goal here is to provide alternative syntax for
class decorator:

```
@decorate
class Foo:
    pass
```

#### Update: Why I ask this in the first place

I wanted to provide a decorator for defining delegated methods/attributes.

```
class Bar:
    def grok(self):
        return 'grok'

@delegate('bar', 'grok')
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar()

foo.grok()
# 'grok'
```

This works fine (gist [here](https://gist.github.com/IwoHerka/4f2fc5ede12e8f3560faa4c91c57bd7e)) *but* it gets a bit ugly if I'm delegating more than a couple of attributes:

```
@delegate('bar', 'first, 'second', 'third', 'fourth')
class Foo:
    ...
```

So, I was wondering if it's possible do to it *inside* class definition itself. Something similar to Ruby syntax:

```
class Foo
    def_delegators :bar :grok
```

Doing it *after* the class is unoptimal because the reader than miss it.

Full `delegate` definition:

```
class Delegated(object):
    def __init__(self, delegated_name, attr):
        self.attr_name = attr
        self.delegated_name = delegated_name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return getattr(self.delegate(instance), self.attr_name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(self.delegate(instance), self.attr_name, value)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        delattr(self.delegate(instance), self.attr_name)

    def delegate(self, instance):
        return getattr(instance, self.delegated_name)


class delegate(object):
    def __init__(self, src, *attrs):
        self.src = src
        self.attrs = attrs

    def __call__(this, cls):
        for attr in this.attrs:
            setattr(cls, attr, Delegated(this.src, attr))
        return cls
```

Comment: why not make it a method of the class?

Comment: Because I want to modify/inspect the class itself, not provide a functionality to it. :)

Comment: When you say you want to acces `Foo` what do you want to access exactly ? The `__init__` method ? Or do you already have a Foo object ?

Comment: Plus, it's partially a curiosity.

Comment: Perhaps you will get better answers if you explain why do you want an alternative to a class decorator. Are you interested in instrumentation?

Comment: It's just a "proof-of-concept" question. I'm asking if it's possible. I know I can just call a function _after_ class definition.

Comment: I dont get it, why the downvotes?

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I'd say the biggest issue with the question is that it's too general to give a useful answer. The existing answer is "you can't do that" and we can't go any deeper because the question is so generic. If you explain exactly what you want your function to do with the class, we might be able to help more (e.g. maybe you could return something that would go into the class namespace).

Comment: Maybe you could use the `inspect` library to examine the frames on the stack, and do some [inspection on the code object of the calling frame](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack)?  That seems very delicate and unreliable though.  I'm not convinced there's a good reason to do this.  Could you provide an example of code that is supposed to do something, even if it's minor?

Comment: What's definition of the `delegate` decorator?

Comment: It was in the gist, I added it just now

Comment: So I understand what you want to do in the class now, and there are a few approaches that might work (using `__getattr__` perhaps, or just assigning a class variable with the names and then letting a decorator or metaclass do the work). But I'm not sure I understand how the in-class syntax you wish for is more compact than the decorator syntax. Is it just the quotation marks you don't want? That's probably going to be hard to avoid, but maybe you could take a single string that will be `split()`? Almost any solution that could work int he class body could also work with the decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that's running inside a class body in Python can't modify the class object, since the object doesn't exist until after the class body has finished running. However, you could add certain methods or variables to the class namespace that control its behavior in certain ways, or which can be used by other code (such as a decorator or metaclass) to manipulate the class or its namespace.

At the simple end would using `__getattr__` to map certain attribute lookups to another object. You could write a function to generator the `__getattr__` method for you:

```
def delegate_attrs(target, *names):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in names:
            return getattr(getattr(self, target), name)
        else:
            raise AttributeError() # ideally we'd delegate to a superclass here, but we can't
    return __getattr__

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar()

    __getattr__ = delegate_attrs('bar', 'grok')
```

Thought this avoids the decorator syntax, in many ways it's worse than the decorator you already have. It's a bit more awkward since you need to name `__getattr__` explicitly in the assignment, and it won't work for dunder methods or handle setting or deleting delegated attributes. While you can fix some of that (by adding `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` methods, perhaps), it's still not great.

A better solution might be to combine the decorator syntax (so you can manipulate the class object) with an in-class declaration saying what should be delegated where. For instance, you could put a dictionary in a class variable that describes the names to delegate:

```
@delegate  # no arguments here!
class Foo:
    delegate_names = {'bar': ['grok']} # could have more targets and/or names in the dict

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar()
```

It would be pretty simple to change the `delegate` decorator you already have to work with this style of argument passing:

```
def delegate(cls):
    for src, attrs in getattr(cls, "delegate_names", {}).items():
        for attr in attrs:
            setattr(cls, attr, Delegated(src, attr))
    return cls
```

Another approach would be to use the same class variable as above, but use a metaclass instead of a decorator to do the work of setting up the descriptors. The advantage of a metaclass would be that it could be inherited, rather than needing to be applied to every class. If your classes are part of an inheritance hierarchy already, that could make it easy to add (you only need to explicitly add the metaclass to the base classes).

If your concern is just that describing the names you want to delegate with quotation marks and commas takes too many characters, then you should consider allowing a user to pass a single string that will be `split()` so that whitespace can separate the names: `@delegate("bar", "first second third fourth fifth")`. The `namedtuple` type factory allows this style of name passing. All this would need to work in your current code is the addition of the following to the top of the `__init__` method of your decorator class:

```
if len(attrs) == 1:
    attrs = attrs[0].split()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo:
    called_inside_definition()
```

at this point the class doesn't exist yet, so you can't access it. The class is created by python calling the metaclass (`type()` in this case), **after** the `class Foo:` block finishes.